# Auto updating labels in tkinter

Tags: opencv, tkinter, python-imaging-library

With this application I would like to monitor the connected video cameras. The algorithm passes only once through `Frames_video()` so the images do not update.I tried different methods, I tried after, a while that together with `root.update`, but nothing worked. The object-oriented structure was taken from the documentation.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
import numpy
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master=master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.Frames_video()
    
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.caps=[cv2.VideoCapture(0),cv2.VideoCapture(1),cv2.VideoCapture(2),cv2.VideoCapture(3),cv2.VideoCapture(4),cv2.VideoCapture(5),cv2.VideoCapture(6),cv2.VideoCapture(7)]
        self.label_1=tk.Label()
        self.label_1.place(x=110,y=50)
        self.label_2=tk.Label()
        self.label_2.place(x=470,y=50)
        self.label_3=tk.Label()     
        self.label_3.place(x=800,y=50)        
        self.label_4=tk.Label()        
        self.label_4.place(x=110,y=330)
        self.label_5=tk.Label()
        self.label_5.place(x=470,y=330)
        self.label_6=tk.Label()        
        self.label_6.place(x=800,y=330)        
        self.label_7=tk.Label()      
        self.label_7.place(x=110,y=600)        
        self.label_8=tk.Label()
        self.label_8.place(x=470,y=600)
        self.labels=[self.label_1,self.label_2,self.label_3,self.label_4,self.label_5,self.label_6,self.label_7,self.label_8]
        self.port_1=tk.Label(text="Port 1",font=("Curier",16),fg="black")
        self.port_1.place(x=110,y=233,width=81,height=31)
        self.port_2=tk.Label(text="Port 2",font=("Curier",16),fg="black")
        self.port_2.place(x=470,y=233,width=81,height=31)
        self.port_3=tk.Label(text="Port 3",font=("Curier",16),fg="black")
        self.port_3.place(x=800,y=233,width=81,height=31)
        self.port_4=tk.Label(text="Port 4",font=("Curier",16),fg="black")
        self.port_4.place(x=110,y=513,width=81,height=31)
        self.port_5=tk.Label(text="Port 5",font=("Curier",16),fg="black")
        self.port_5.place(x=470,y=513,width=81,height=31)
        self.port_6=tk.Label(text="Port 6",font=("Curier",16),fg="black")
        self.port_6.place(x=800,y=513,width=81,height=31)
        self.port_7=tk.Label(text="Port 7",font=("Curier",16),fg="black")
        self.port_7.place(x=110,y=783,width=81,height=31)
        self.port_8=tk.Label(text="Port 8",font=("Curier",16),fg="black")
        self.port_8.place(x=470,y=783,width=81,height=31)
        self.button_1=tk.Button(text="ScreenShot",font=("Curier",16),bg="gray",fg="black")
        self.button_1.place(x=190,y=231,width=131,height=31)
        self.button_2=tk.Button(text="ScreenShot",font=("Curier",16),bg="gray",fg="black")
        self.button_2.place(x=550,y=231,width=131,height=31)
        self.button_3=tk.Button(text="ScreenShot",font=("Curier",16),bg="gray",fg="black")
        self.button_3.place(x=880,y=231,width=131,height=31)
        self.button_4=tk.Button(text="ScreenShot",font=("Curier",16),bg="gray",fg="black")
        self.button_4.place(x=190,y=511,width=131,height=31)
        self.button_5=tk.Button(text="ScreenShot",font=("Curier",16),bg="gray",fg="black")
        self.button_5.place(x=550,y=511,width=131,height=31)
        self.button_6=tk.Button(text="ScreenShot",font=("Curier",16),bg="gray",fg="black")
        self.button_6.place(x=880,y=511,width=131,height=31)
        self.button_7=tk.Button(text="ScreenShot",font=("Curier",16),bg="gray",fg="black")
        self.button_7.place(x=190,y=781,width=131,height=31)
        self.button_8=tk.Button(text="ScreenShot",font=("Curier",16),bg="gray",fg="black")
        self.button_8.place(x=550,y=781,width=131,height=31)
        img=cv2.imread(r'Aqua_logo.png')
        img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img=Image.fromarray(img)
        img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        self.logo=tk.Label(image=img)
        self.logo.image=img
        self.logo.place(x=820,y=600)
    def Frames_video(self):
        for i in range(8):
            ret,frame=self.caps[i].read()
            frame=cv2.resize(frame,(211,181))
            img=frame
            img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img=Image.fromarray(img)
            img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            self.labels[i].configure(image=img)
            self.labels[i].image=img


window =tk.Tk()
window.geometry("1124x889")
app=Application(master=window)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the issue when you tried to use `after()`?

Comment: runs to infinity

Comment: maybe I didn't implement it correctly, can you show me how it would be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a new thread for each device. Store the label reference and corresponding image in some form of data structure. Then run an update method at regular intervals to update the label with the corresponding image.

Here is an example (expand on the same):

```py
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from threading import Thread
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class LabelImg: 
    label: tk.Label
    img: Image = None


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master=master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
    
    def create_widgets(self):
        
        
        self.label_1=tk.Label()
        self.label_1.place(x=110,y=50)
        self.label_2=tk.Label()
        self.label_2.place(x=470,y=50)

        self.port_1=tk.Label(text="Port 1",font=("Curier",16),fg="black")
        self.port_1.place(x=110,y=233,width=81,height=31)
        self.port_2=tk.Label(text="Port 2",font=("Curier",16),fg="black")
        self.port_2.place(x=470,y=233,width=81,height=31)

        self.button_1=tk.Button(text="ScreenShot",font=("Curier",16),bg="gray",fg="black")
        self.button_1.place(x=190,y=231,width=131,height=31)
        self.button_2=tk.Button(text="ScreenShot",font=("Curier",16),bg="gray",fg="black")
        self.button_2.place(x=550,y=231,width=131,height=31)


        self.video_attr = [LabelImg(self.label_1),
                                 LabelImg(self.label_2)]

        self.start()

    def start(self):
        self.stop()
        
        self.running = True
        for index, frame in enumerate(self.video_attr):
            thread = Thread(target=self.frames_video, args=(frame, index))
            thread.start()

        self.update_frames()

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

    def update_frames(self):
        
        if self.running:
            for item in self.video_attr:
                if item.img:
                    item.label.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(item.img)
                    item.label.config(image=item.label.img)
            
            self.after(10, self.update_frames)


    def frames_video(self, frameattr, device=0):
    
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(device)
        
        while self.running:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            
            if ret:
                frame = cv2.resize(frame, (211, 181))
                img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                frameattr.img = Image.fromarray(img)

        cap.release()

def handle_close():
    app.stop()
    window.destroy()

window =tk.Tk()
window.geometry("1124x889")

app=Application(master=window)

window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", handle_close)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.after()` to keep getting frames from those cameras as below:

```py
def Frames_video(self, i=0):
    ret, frame = self.caps[i].read()
    if ret:
        img = cv2.resize(frame, (211,181))
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = Image.fromarray(img)
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        self.labels[i].configure(image=img)
        self.labels[i].image = img
    # you can adjust the delay (5ms) to other value to suit your case
    window.after(5, self.Frames_video, (i+1)%8)
```